# JavaScript: How to make images display at the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, image, button

I have multiple buttons (with the ids 'a', 'b', ...) and if you click them, they should display their corresponding image ('a.JPG', 'b.JPG', ...) at a fixed point on the website.

The idea is to listen for when a button is clicked and change the code inside the output to include its id.

```
'use strict';
var bild = '', i, j, k;

function gedrueckt(k) {
    bild = '<img src="img/' + k + '.JPG" width="1600" hight="900" alt="Vergroessertes Bild"></img>';
    document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = bild;
}

for (i = 1; i < 8; i = i + 1) {
    j = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
    document.getElementById(j).addEventListener('click', gedrueckt(j));
}
```

The problem is that an image already appears before any button is clicked and pressing a different button does not change the displayed image.

Comment: could you please add a portion of your HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

This code should change the src on each button click, changing the picture according the the ID of the button:

```js
let img = document.getElementById('img')
const change = id => {
  img.src = `${id}.jpeg`
  img.alt = `${id}.jpeg`
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="">
<br>
<button onclick="change(this.id)" id="a">A</button>
<button onclick="change(this.id)" id="b">B</button>
<button onclick="change(this.id)" id="c">C</button>
```

> If there no `src` and no `alt` property provided, the image will not be displayed.

I might've misunderstood you, in that you want the image to change on keyboard button press, which this code should do the trick:

```js
let img = document.getElementById('img')
const change = id => {
  img.src = `${id}.jpeg`
  img.alt = `${id}.jpeg`
}

const list = ['a','b','c']

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => list.includes(e.key) && change(e.key))
```

```html
<img id="img" src="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the buttons and attach an `click` listener to it. Create `img` element on `button` click and append it to the element with `id` output.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.id + '.jpg';
    output.innerHTML = "";
    output.appendChild(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="a">one</button>
<button id="b">two</button>
<button id="c">three</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```